# How to get a bean in a Service class?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I'm trying to define a configuration for ModelMapper that can be shared by all other classes.
I created a Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    protected final ModelMapper mapper;

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper getMapper() {
        mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<MerchantDTO, Merchant>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                skip(destination.getId());
            }
        });
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

but when I use constructor DI in another service:

```
private final ModelMapper mapper;
```

I get an error that

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
```

Answer (score 0):

Tis is how we used:

Config file:

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.addMappings(ModelMapperConfig.userToUserDTO());
    return modelMapper;
  }
}
```

Config for deep mapping:

```
import org.modelmapper.PropertyMap;

class ModelMapperConfig {

static PropertyMap<User, UserDTO> userToUserDTO() {
    return new PropertyMap<>() {
        protected void configure() {
            map().setOfficeName(source.getOffice().getOfficeName());
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

Service:

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {

    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public DemoServiceImpl(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
      this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
 }
```

So you can use it.